# php max() function gives wrong result

Tags: php, max

I'm trying to find the max value of each row in a file using php. My input looks like this.

```
1x5x10
1x10x5
5x1x10
5x10x1
10x1x5
10x5x1
```

My code:

```
<?php

$myfile = fopen("day2_input.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($myfile)) {
    $line = fgets($myfile);

    $lineArr = explode("x", $line);

    echo(max($lineArr)."\n");
}

fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Here is the strange thing. As you see in the input, the maximum value of each row is 10, but here is my output:

```
5
5

5
10
5

10
```

Including an empty line at the end. Two questions. Why does the `max()`-function give something else than 10? And why the empty lines in the output? There are no spaces in the input file at the end of the lines. I also checkd the arrays using `print_r()` on `$lineArr` which gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 10

)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 5

)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 10

)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 1

)
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 5

)
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your explode is creating an array of strings, not of integers.... so max applies string comparison logic, and `10` is less than `5` alphabetically.

convert your string elements to integers, and then do the max() call.... something like:

```
$lineArr = array_map('intval', explode("x", $line));
```

Comment: @BluePrint - Mark Baker beat me to it by 3 seconds - please accept his answer :)

Answer (score 4):

They are being converted to strings and are being compared alphanumerically. Do a var_dump($lineArr) rather than a print_r($lineArr) to confirm this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

"multiple string values will be compared alphanumerically"

Use:

```
$lineArr = array_map('intval', explode('x', $line));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the output of `$lineArr`, there is a newline in the third element of each explode result. You have to trim newline character from the source line before explosion, like the following:

```
$line = fgets($myfile);
$line = trim($line, " \t\r\n"); // this string to be added
```

and it will work right as you expect.